# Sequelize Associate Objects fails with has no method addX

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Trying to associate a phone number with a user is resulting in node telling me that the User object has no method addPhonenumber. (also happens with setPhonenumber)

```
req.user.setPhonenumbers(phonenumber).success(function(user){
             ^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setPhonenumbers'
```

How do I properly associate objects? Code below.

Object definitions in models.js:

```
exports.User = require("./user")(sequelize, Sequelize);
exports.Phonenumber = require("./phonenumber")(sequelize, Sequelize);
exports.Recording = require("./recording")(sequelize, Sequelize);
exports.Call = require("./call")(sequelize, Sequelize);

User
  .hasMany(Phonenumber)
  .hasMany(Recording);

Phonenumber
  .belongsTo(User)
  .hasOne(Recording)
  .hasMany(Call);

Recording.belongsTo(User);

Call.belongsTo(Phonenumber);
```

Trying to set association:

```
      var phonenumber = yp.db.Phonenumber.create({
        number: number.phone_number
      }).success(function(number){
        console.log(number);
        console.log(req.user);
        req.user.setPhonenumbers(phonenumber).success(function(user){
          console.log(user);
        });
      });
```

And the console.log result of the above referenced req.user:

```
{ __options: 
   { timestamps: true,
     instanceMethods: { fullname: [Function] },
     classMethods: {},
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: false,
     underscored: false,
     syncOnAssociation: true,
     paranoid: true,
     omitNull: false,
     hasPrimaryKeys: false },
  hasPrimaryKeys: false,
  selectedValues: 
   { firstname: 'Nathan',
     lastname: 'Loyer',
     email: 'xxx@gmail.com',
     password: '****',
     facebookid: '****',
     id: 2,
     createdAt: Thu Feb 28 2013 20:40:29 GMT-0600 (CST),
     updatedAt: Wed Mar 06 2013 20:22:05 GMT-0600 (CST),
     deletedAt: null },
  firstname: 'Nathan',
  lastname: 'Loyer',
  email: 'xxx@gmail.com',
  password: '****',
  facebookid: '****',
  id: 2,
  createdAt: Thu Feb 28 2013 20:40:29 GMT-0600 (CST),
  updatedAt: Wed Mar 06 2013 20:22:05 GMT-0600 (CST),
  deletedAt: null,
  isNewRecord: false }
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your hasMany needs a matching belongsTo. And, the associated function will be setPhonenumbers. See: http://www.sequelizejs.com/documentation#associations-associating-objects

Comment: I have updated my associations above, and used setPhonenumbers although the documentation lists the addTask function in the section below the one you pointed out. Results are still the same however.

Comment: Could you please replace your examples with files that actually run. We need to actually be able to run your code to debug it, if the answer isn't obvious.

Comment: Since you wouldn't be able to run this code without the entire project, which I'm unable to share in completion due to this being a client's property, are you suggesting I just write a quick one page with these associations and try to set it to a static value? And if that works, how will we get closer to the actual solution?

Comment: I've found the problem, thanks for the suggestion, it caused me to notice an anomaly. Will explain below.

Comment: Going to give you credit since your request for running code caused me to stumble over my error.

Comment: Thanks for the credit. Simplifying the problem to the point that you can post here about it often brings you to the solution. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a problem of not being strict enough with my naming. In the model definition for the phonenumber model, I used Number instead of Phonenumber.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize){

  return sequelize.define('Number',{
    number: Sequelize.STRING,
  },{
    paranoid: true
  });

}
```

So it created a setNumbers function, not a setPhonenumbers function. Changing this to Phonenumber instead and re-creating the tables made the above code almost work. setPhonenumbers seemed to want an array, so I used addPhonenumber instead.